# Assigning an ID to a sequence when using partition clauses in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

When attempting to identify a specific sequence using a partition by clause, it is possible to label each of the rows in a partition with row_number.

```sql
select *, 
       row_number() over(partition by x,y order by z desc) as rn,
from table ;
```

How would you go about assigning a specific ID like a hash to each partition?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The row number will already be unique across the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the partitions using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by x, y order by z desc) as with_partition_seqnum,
       dense_rank() over (order by x, y) as partition_seqnum
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate has is `HASH_BYTES` function:

```
SELECT *, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(x, '^', y)) AS hash FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=121ec1811322f4176c543cc837ad71be)**